# System, Reports Menu not show in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, adminmenu

Today i just try to login at my magento website backend and "Report" and "System" menu is not showing, I google it alot to find the solution but i didn't get any thing. I am using magento 1.9.2.3 i didn't update any thing. 
yesterday i just disable the module paypaluk and today i just try to activate cloudflare.com with my polorepublica.biz website and disable it.

Please guide me what should i do to recover my menus back. 
thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO admin_user
SELECT
NULL user_id,
"Ashish" firstname,
"Madankar" lastname,
"ashish@test.com" email,
"ashish" username,
"e58d34d72aefb6d6f6c6e419da695252:at" password,
NOW( ) created,
NULL modified,
NULL logdate,
0 lognum,
0 reload_acl_flag,
1 is_active,
(SELECT MAX(extra) FROM admin_user WHERE extra IS NOT NULL) extra,
NULL rp_token,
NOW() rp_token_created_at;

INSERT into admin_role
SELECT
NULL role_id,
(SELECT role_id FROM admin_role WHERE role_name = 'Administrators') parent_id,
2 tree_level,
0 sort_order,
'U' role_type,
(SELECT user_id FROM admin_user WHERE username = 'ashish') user_id,
'ashish' role_name
```

Execute the above SQL in you DB which will create new user in your system with **ashish** as a user name and **12345678** as password login with this and check if menu is available or not. if it is available then check permission of you role and make changes in that account. you can change the user name.

Hope this will help you.